# Saving existent CSV file in Android with Processing

Tags: java, android, csv, processing

I am new in android programming and I am struggeling with saving an existent CSV file. I wrote the Code with Java in Processing. and it works on the PC but now I would like to switch to android Mode - but how can I Move the CSV file to my phone? and is there an easy way so i can use the Command:

```
table = loadTable("Vocstest.csv", "header");
```

I use Processing 3.37

Comment: My guess is you need to package the CSV file up with your app. You should probably take a step back and learn about the Android file system before you continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote will work just fine on an android phone. I have used the same code as yours in an app.

The difference may be that i do not try to override it (by saving) I am only accessing it to retrieve the data.

You have to add your file in the "data" directory in your project. If the "data" folder does not exist you can create it and put in your csv file.

example:

```
  Table aQaK = loadTable("aQaK_ar.csv", "header");
  TableRow myrow = aQaK.getRow(myversenum);
  String myversetxt = myrow.getString("AyahText");
```

Hope this helps. Peace.